# How to compile all .c files in a directory and output each binary without the .c extension

Tags: c, makefile

I have a directory with multiple c source files (every file is a small program by itself) which I would like to compile all at once and output the binary for each one in the subdirectory bin/. The name of the binary should be the one of the c source file, but without the .c extension.
How could I accomplish something like that in a Makefile?

Example:

```
-src
    ll.c
    lo.c
    -bin
        ll
        lo
```

The first thing I came up with is this:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
SRC=$(wildcard *.c)

all: $(SRC)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) -o bin/$(SRC)
```

But this does not really work how I thought it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `all: $(SRC)` tells make that the `all` target has *every* source file as a prerequisite.

The recipe for that target (`gcc $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) -o bin/$(SRC)`) then tries to run gcc on *all* the source files and tells it to create as output the `bin/<first word in`$(SRC)`with the rest of the words from`$(SRC)` being other, extra, arguments to gcc.

You want something more like this:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
# This is a substitution reference. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs
BINS := $(SRCS:%.c=bin/%)

CFLAGS=-Wall -g

# Tell make that the all target has every binary as a prequisite and tell make that it will not create an `all` file (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets).
.PHONY: all
all: $(BINS)

bin:
    mkdir $@

# Tell make that the binaries in the current directory are intermediate files so it doesn't need to care about them directly (and can delete them). http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eINTERMEDIATE
# This keeps make from building the binary in the current directory a second time if you run `make; make`.
.INTERMEDIATE: $(notdir $(BINS))

# Tell make that it should delete targets if their recipes error. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eDELETE_005fON_005fERROR 
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

# This is a static pattern rule to tell make how to handle all the `$(BINS)` files. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern
$(BINS) : bin/% : % | bin
        mv $^ $@
```

Answer (score 0):

[I overlooked where you said you wanted to do this in a Makefile.  My solution here is straight shell.]

I would use something like

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

for cfile in *.c
do
    cc $CFLAGS -o bin/`basename $cfile .c` $cfile
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Make is smart enough to do it with implicit rules.  Make sure no makefile exists and run:

```
  for f in *.c; do make CFLAGS='-Wall -g' ${f%.c} && mv ${f%.c} bin; done
```

Comment: While true this isn't smart enough to rebuild only what is necessary. But you just gave me an idea for my answer in progress, so thanks.