# How to invoke command for each file using make?

Tags: makefile

So I am struggling a bit with the following Makefile:

```
src := $(wildcard *.c)
bin := $(src:%.c=out/%)

.PHONY: all
all: $(bin)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -r out

out:
    mkdir $@

$(bin): $(src) | out
    $(CC) -Iincludes/ -Wall $< -o $@
```

Let's say I have the following directory:

```
$ ls
includes/ Makefile test1.c test2.c
```

Then I want the following to happen:

```
$ make
mkdir out
cc -Iincludes/ -Wall test1.c -o out/test2
cc -Iincludes/ -Wall test2.c -o out/test1
```

But what actually happens:

```
$ make
mkdir out
cc -Iincludes/ -Wall test2.c -o out/test2
cc -Iincludes/ -Wall test2.c -o out/test1
```

I kinda do not want to move files around what other solutions [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191857/how-to-compile-all-c-files-in-a-directory-and-output-each-binary-without-the-c)

I am pretty sure this has to be easy but I am lost. Thank you for your help.

Comment: See the answer I just gave to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647943/cannot-get-makefile-to-build-each-object-from-its-corresponding-source ; this is the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing the '$(bin)' rule:

```
out/%: %.c
    $(CC) -Iincludes/ -Wall $< -o $@
```

The existing rule indicate that each program depends on ALL source files, and that each program can be built by compiling the ($<) FIRST source file. The revised rule indicate that echh programs depends on the .c with the same name